# Button control style template and BackgroundSizing Property

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have some problem with Button Style template.
I tried to change button background when mouse hover on button.
When I created style sheet for it by right-clicking mouse on xaml design viewer - click on copy template.

successfully, I got a Control Template "Resource Dictionary" of Button Control.
But I got a error message when I compiled it. I could compile it without definition of style sheet. I could find a error message with a BackgroundSizing Property.

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BackgroundSizing" Value="OuterBorderEdge"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForeground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPadding}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BackgroundSizing="{TemplateBinding BackgroundSizing}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups> 
<---omitted---->
```

[image]

First one is another problem, and 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th are the problem relative with button control template.

I deleted a BackgroundSizing property. then I don't get any error message, but app stop. so when I run app with debug mode, I cound find this error.

[image]

when I set Target version 1809, then all problem solved....

But I heard that some device needs to target lower version(?) maybe..

How can I solve BackgroundSizing Property error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BackgroundSizing` was actually introduced in Windows 10, version 1809 (introduced v10.0.17763.0), so that's why it's working on 1809 build and not on the build version lower than it. You can refer to this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.backgroundsizing) documentation.

In order to resolve this issue, you have to use conditional Xaml.

You can create a style like this:

**BaseButtonStyle**

```
 <Style x:Key="BaseButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForeground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPadding}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BackgroundSizing="{TemplateBinding BackgroundSizing}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups> 
<---omitted---->
```

**ButtonStyle1**

```
 <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button" BasedOn={StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}>
    <Setter Property="BackgroundSizing" Value="OuterBorderEdge"/>
 </Style>
```

And now you can consume this style as below:

```
<Page
    x:Class="ConditionalTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:contract7NotPresent="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation?IsApiContractNotPresent(Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract,7)"
xmlns:contract7Present="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation?IsApiContractPresent(Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract,7)">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button contract7Present:Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}"
                contract7NotPresent:Style="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Thank you @Dishant, but Im sorry that I still have question mark on that. without writing conditional xaml that you advised, Just setting target version 1809 and min version lower than 1809, then will I have problem on version issue? After wrote this question post, I found the ‘BrushTransition’ in splitview template style and It also needs setting target 1809.

Comment: ah, never mind. without conditional xaml, I should set both target version and min version to 1809 to compile. So, I always need to use conditional xaml with 1809 to cover lower version..... now I understand. Thank you.